# Ubuntu Server 12.04 - Create a non-Root user with own Userdir

Tags: 12.04, server, apache2, user-profile

I've created a new non-root user, `dev`, that so far does not belong to any groups, and I've been following [this guide](http://kimbriggs.com/computers/computer-notes/linux-notes/apache2-public_html-virtual-directories.file) to help me setup Apache for hosting sites under this user's **public_html** directory (this is a development machine). As this new user does not belong to the `sudoers` group, I'm now having the obvious problem of trying to create the following symbolic links when logged in as the new user (under Step2 in the linked article):

```
sudo ln -s ../mods-available/userdir.conf userdir.conf
sudo ln -s ../mods-available/userdir.load userdir.load
```

Also, if I browse to `http://192.168.1.100/dev` I get a 404 not found response, when I should at least be seeing some sort of file/folder structure (assuming I did everything correctly).

What workaround is there to this? Better yet, what is the correct method of setting up the `public_html` folder for a non-root user. I'm doing this in an effort to learn as well as ensure that a non-root user is being used to create any sites....am I being too paranoid about getting the security right?

Many thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To enable apaches's userdir module run: `sudo a2enmod userdir`. You have to do this as a user able to `sudo`. Don't forget to restart apache: `sudo service apache2 restart`.

Then dev's public_html directory will be available at `http://192.168.1.100/~dev`.

Comment: thanks! appears I forgot the tilde (~)! would you suggest that I add my user to the sudoer's group?

Comment: oh wait...(*facepalm moment*)...I should `sudo a2enmod userdir` as root user instead

Comment: Exactly, run `a2enmod userdir` as root once and userdir will be enabled permanently for all users.

Comment: and then run `mkdir public_html` as non-root user?

Comment: I'm also adding the user to the `www-data` group and then changing the permissions on that folder to `chmod 2750 /public_html` whilst under the home directory for the non-root user.

Comment: It should be `chmod 2750 public_html`. Make sure the group allowed to access public_html is www-data: `chgrp -R www-data public_html`.

Comment: I'm already allowing access using: `chown -R dev:www-data /home/dev/public_html` after running `usermod -a -G www-data dev`...the former command will do the same as your `chgrp`, correct?

Comment: Yes, it's correct.